# Doctrine Annotation failing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb, silex

Currently I'm trying to implement the [Doctrine CouchDB Bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle) in a Silex Application. At one point the complete site ends in a `500/internal server error` in my local dev stack. Setting breakpoints and debugging them with XDebug and PHPStorm hasn't brought me to any result so far. Apache Error logs are empty, PHP error logs as well and `error_reporting(-1);` still doesn't give any output. Probably the problem is the reflection class usage in there.

Everything works well, ***until*** I try to use CouchDB Annotations from

```
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations as CouchDB;
```

and use them in my Document

```
/** @CouchDB\Document */
class Station
{
    /**
     * @Index
     * @Id
     */
    private $id;
```

If I remove the `CouchDB\` above, everything works. But if I remove it, and use `@Id(strategy="ASSIGNED")`, I run into the exact same problem.

I tried to register the Annotations in several ways without luck. @Ocramius suggested in chat that I should simply override the Autoloader, which worked well with getting beyond some other problems, but not for that case (just adding it here in case someone else needs it).

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader( function( $className ) {
    return class_exists( $className );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
/**
* @CouchDB\Index
* @CouchDB\Id
*/
```

instead of

```
/**
* @Index
* @Id
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly that doesn't work. I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is that I somehow haven't loaded the needed Annotation class (unlikely as I `use`-included it). Point as well is, that the CouchDB Annotations should just align the default Doctrine annotations. So - in theory - it should work without the `CouchDB` at the `Index` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by adding this line before you run your Silex Application (probably in index.php).

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
```